# postgresql count the top 3 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I know we can use LIMIT in PostreSQL to get the top 3 values in the relation but what if there are duplicate values. For example, 
5
4
4
3
2

Ordering it in DESC order and using LIMIT 3 will just return 5,4,4. But how do we get 5,4,4,3 (The top 3 with duplicates).

I know how to do this the long way but I was wondering if there are any PostreSQL built in things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way would be to use the [`dense_rank` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to rank the values as desired and then peel off those with the desired ranks.

For example, given this:

```
create table t (
  id serial not null primary key, -- just a placeholder so that we can differentiate the duplicate `c`s.
  c int not null
);
insert into t (c)
values (1), (1), (2), (3), (4), (4), (4), (5);
```

you'd presumably want the rows with `c` in `(5,4,3)` and you could do that with:

```
select id, c
from (
  select id, c, dense_rank() over (order by c desc) as r
  from t
) dt
where r <= 3
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b262/8

Note that you need to use `dense_rank` rather than `rank` because `rank` will arrange things in the right order but it will leave gaps in the rankings so `r <= 3` wouldn't necessarily work. Compare the `r` values in the above fiddle with `dense_rank` and `rank` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have below record

index  Name
1   "ABC" 
2   "XYZ" 
2   "ABC" 
1   "XYZ" 
1   "XYZ"

in this case you can distinct to choose non duplicate record.

```
Select distinct index, name from table_name;
```